# Add a "fixed" div in responsive footer menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

In the following w3schools code that implements a responsive menu at the bottom of a webpage, I have added a div with a copyright claim for the domain. I would like to make the copyright div **centered in the bottom of the screen** as long as it is not covered by the menu items, as the browser window gets smaller, **and then move again at the bottom of the page** bellow the menu items when it gets covered by them or when the menu is opened by the relative button when it previously has minimized.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
  if (x.className === "navbar") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "navbar";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.navbar .icon {
  display: none;
}

#copyright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar" id="myNavbar">
    <div id="copyright">© domain.com</div>
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>

  <div style="padding-left:16px">
    <h2>Responsive Bottom Navbar Example</h2>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Any ideas for a good implementation are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You Go I also added Browser Support, since you mention that it didn't look right on your browser. I commented more so you can get a sense of what is going on.

```js
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
    if (x.className === "navbar") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "navbar";
    }
  }
```

```css
/*
* Prefixed by https://autoprefixer.github.io
* PostCSS: v8.3.6,
* Autoprefixer: v10.3.1
* Browsers: last 7 version
*/

  /*
  Body
  */

  body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

  /*
  The Navigation Container/Block
  */

  .navbar {
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  /*
  Grid Container
  */

  .grid-container {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }

  /*
  Item 1
  */

  .item-1 {
    text-align: end;
  }

  /*
  Item 2
  */

  .item-2 {
    color: white;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
  }

  /*
  Item 3
  */

  .item-3 {
    text-align: end;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
        -ms-flex-pack: end;
            justify-content: flex-end;
  }

  .item-3 a {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }

  .item-3 a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
  }

  .item-3 a.active {
    background-color: #04aa6d;
    color: white;
  }

  /*
  Toggle Icon For Menu
  */

  .navbar .icon {
    display: none;
  }

  /*
  This Will Display In Media Queries
  */

  .copyright-bottom {
    display: none;
  }

  /*
  Media Queries
  */

  @media screen and (max-width: 970px) {
    .item-3 a {
      display: none;
    }

    .navbar a.icon {
      display: block;
    }

    .navbar.responsive .icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }

    .navbar.responsive a {
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .navbar.responsive .copyright-bottom {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }

    .navbar.responsive .copyright {
      display: none;
    }

    .navbar.responsive .item-3 {
      -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
      grid-column: span 3;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
          -ms-flex-direction: column;
              flex-direction: column;
      -webkit-box-align: start;
          -ms-flex-align: start;
              align-items: flex-start;
      -webkit-box-pack: start;
          -ms-flex-pack: start;
              justify-content: flex-start;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar" id="myNavbar">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item-1"></div>
    <div class="item-2">
      <p class="copyright">© domain.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-3">
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size: 15px" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"
        >&#9776;</a
      >
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="copyright-bottom">© domain.com</p>
</div>

<div style="padding-left: 16px">
  <h2>Responsive Bottom Navbar Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I deleted my first comment after testing your code and making appropriate changes to fit it in my own site. Two things: The footer is narrower than in the original code. Why is that? And my second issue is that the copyright text initially is not centered in the middle of the screen, but in the middle of the left side of the screen and the leftmost menu button. That's all. Otherwise, the code works perfectly!

Comment: Another thing that could be changed is this: When the menu has gotten expanded by pressing the button it covers part of the content of the page. When the user scrolls the content of the page ideally the text shouldn't be hidden by the menu. The same should be true for the initial menu. It should not cover any text. If I set a wider height for the initial menu, it also covers the content of the page, even when I have scrolled to the bottom.

Comment: I used Grid instead of flex-box. You can get more info grid just by browsing around.

Comment: Are you sure that this version works? I haven't tested it in my site, but here in Stackoverflow, when I hit the Run code snippet button, I always see the menu items hidden and I have to click the button to expand them. I don't see any reaction to window size changes. The previous code worked with minor issues.

Comment: @Costas You the menu hidden because its the window is responsive. In the upper right hand-corner there's a full page icon so that you can test how it looks in full-size window.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The previous code worked even without expanding the window, so I didn't think of testing it in full window mode now.
You are right the code works fine!

Comment: I have just one issue with this code. In pages where the content is long enough, the footer at the bottom covers the last part of the content of the page. Even when I scroll to the bottom a portion at the end stays covered. Is there a way to avoid the overlay of the div with the `class="navbar"` with the div that contains the page content?

Comment: @Costas Do you mean the Content of the page overlays the class="navbar" where you can't see the Navbar anymore?. Add a code inside class="navbar" of "index: Value; and the value can range from -5 to 5 (e.x index: 5;). Play with the number until you're satisfy.

Comment: The other way around. The footer stays on top of the content.

Comment: I want to add some information. This happens in all browsers (Edge, Firefox, Opera) except Chrome. By the way I added some lines in your code. For example where you had  `-webkit-box-pack: start;` I added below it  `-moz-box-pack: start;      -ms-box-pack: start;` because I was notified by the editor I use to do so. I have made similar browser specific modification in other parts of your code to.

Comment: I just removed all the browser specific instructions. Still the same behavior.

Comment: @Costas I'm confused a bit. So you want the the navigation bar at the bottom but when it opens the menu for the menu to not cover the content of the page at the same time?.

Comment: The navigation bar covers the last part of the content in the three browsers I mentioned, with the exception of Chrome as I said. I'm referring to the initial navigation bar, not the one expanded by the button when the window is narrow. I want the navigation bar to not cover the content of the page.

Comment: @Costas sorry not catching on. Not sure how that would work having the navbar at the bottom and not covering the content. Another way of doing this is giving the nav bar transparent color so that it doesn't cover much but it not 100%.

Comment: Well it works in chrome. The navbar stays out of the way of the content. In the other browsers, when I scroll to the bottom still part of the content stays covered.

I don't think though that the expectable behavior of a footer is make part of the content inaccessible, so probably there is a solution.

By the way, if you can edit your answer, you can remove all the browser specific instructions. I did it and I don't see any difference in the appearance of the navbar in any of the 4 browsers.

Comment: @Costas I just tried it in firefox and it work the same. Another way of doing this is wrapping a div with a class around all your elements then add height: 90vh; overflow: auto;. This  way the nav bar doesn't even cover the content. try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238985/discussion-between-costas-and-joseph).

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
  if (x.className === "navbar") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "navbar";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.navbar .icon {
  display: none;
}

#copyright {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar {
    display: block;
  }

  .navbar a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }

  #copyright {
    margin: 5px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar" id="myNavbar">
    <div id="copyright">© domain.com</div>
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>

  <div style="padding-left:16px">
    <h2>Responsive Bottom Navbar Example</h2>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It has 2 issues. Number one: When the window gets narrower the footer gets taller and the copyright stays at the top of it. Also when the menu gets expanded with the button the copyright stays above the menu.